# How is this script working and why can't a user select the message box in developers tool to remove it

Tags: javascript, debugging

Go to https://app.sequoiahack.com/ in chrome browser. Don't put you email id and just click "Get started". It will prompt you to fill out email field,don't do it just close the tab. Now the message box is still there (stucked). I tried to delete it using chrome developers tools but can't select it to remove it from html code. I am interested in knowing how can a developer create such a box and whats the cleaning activity/code required to remove it which developer has forgotten to add in the application/web page code. Please see attached screenshot.

Link for the screenshot --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCake.png

Comment: Just click outside of the e-mail field and it will be gone.

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('email')[0].required = false;`
will bypass it in this step - but..., there is another precaution you will need to overcome

Answer (score 0):

That's just a standard input element with the "required" attribute. Chrome does some validation when you try to submit the form, and one thing it does is show that prompt if the input element has the "required" attribute.

You could remove that prompt, by right clicking input field, choosing "Inspect Element" and then removing the "required" attribute. If you remove that attribute the form should submit without that prompt appearing (but server-side validation should catch it and you'll get some other kind of prompt for an email address, a prompt that a web developer actually has control over).

I can't reproduce it persisting onto other tabs, but it could just be a bug in your version of Chrome. It is not something the web developer of that website did, and it is not something that is possible for a web developer to control.

Comment: Umm, I am not able do anything with the stuck message ,right click doesn't show any menu options .may be its a bug in chrome .

Comment: @saket I know, you could right-click the input element though, before clicking "Get Started" in the first place (just to confirm that the only thing creating that message is the required attribute on the input element)